# Jquery ajax return null

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I am using the Jquery function,

```
function ajax_fun(id,val)
{
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { pid: 1, cart_id: id, val: val },
    success: function (returndata){
       console.log(returndata);
    }  
});
}
```

**Call**

```
ajax_fun(1,100);
```

**data.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['pid']) && $_GET['pid']==1)
{

  $cart_id = $_GET['cart_id'];
  $val  = $_GET['val']+0.06;
  $arr = array('cart_id'=> $cart_id, 'total' => $val);
  json_encode($arr);
}
?>
```

Console returns **'null'** . It didn't return cart_id and total.

Can anyone help?

.

Comment: You didn't `echo` the output..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
json_encode($arr);
```

shoule be

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

You forget to `echo` the result.

***Full code:***

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['pid']) && $_GET['pid']==1) {
  $cart_id = $_GET['cart_id'];
  $val  = $_GET['val']+0.06;
  $arr = array('cart_id'=> $cart_id, 'total' => $val);
  echo json_encode($arr); // write echo before json_encode($arr)
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

RE-Write this line as...

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 'echo' before json_encode which return the data

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['pid']) && $_GET['pid']==1)
{

  $cart_id = $_GET['cart_id'];
  $val  = $_GET['val']+0.06;
  $arr = array('cart_id'=> $cart_id, 'total' => $val);
  echo json_encode($arr);
}
?>
```